# I want to reach for a route from a form

Tags: html, laravel, forms, routes, controller

I'm new to laravel and i wanna make a sign up form. But i dont manage to acces the route from my form.

This is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('subscription.save') }}">
     @csrf
     @method('post')
....
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

and this is my route:

> `Route::post('/subscription', function() { dd(33); })->name('subscription.save');`

On button submit, it should display the dd(33)

If i delete the route entirely, it gives the error:"Route [subscription.save] not defined."

I actually want to reach for a function 'store' in 'SubscriptionController', where i also have a dd, but I adapted my code to search for the error.

Comment: "_But i dont manage to acces the route from my form_" Why not? What happens? Blank page? Wrong route? An error shows up (which one)?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no error, it just closes my modal and doesn't do my dd

Comment: php artisan r:l try

Comment: Did you try the same form outside the modal? It looks like your action only close your modal and don't do the post.

Comment: i try know from outside of the modal

Comment: yes, it works from outside of the modal and after i added the route there, it works from the modal too. Why is that? And how to make it work from inside the modal

Comment: The problem isn't from Laravel. You should have some javascript somewhere preventing the form to be posted

Comment: ok. what javascript

Comment: Is the modal placed inside of another form maybe?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should not use `@method('post')`, as you already use method attribute in form tag. we use @method() in case we are sending PUT/PATCH request from form tag.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('subscription.save') }}">
     @csrf
     @method('PUT/PATCH')

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Note: incase you use PUT/PATCH make sure you are using PUT/PATCH with ROUTE in web.php.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question. The OP is using POST and not PUT. The `@method()` is not needed, but not a problem.

Comment: yes you are right, i just want to say that @method() will be used in case of PUT/PATCH, but not with POST.
this is optional only incase of PUT/PATCH request